# Cannot browse through the localhost

Tags: iis, iis-6

I am new to IIS Configurations. When I browse through http:\localhost\ in windows server 2012 it shows the page cannot be displayed. How do I verify the IIS is configured correct.

Comment: The web server role is not enabled by default, so expected.

Comment: Assuming .NET runtime 4.0. Open a command prompt as admin. 1. Type cd c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v4.0.30319 and press enter. 2. Type aspnet_regiis - i